# How to recover a .java class in an Eclipse project?

Tags: eclipse

I opened the Eclipse as usual from an installer (I downloaded the complete jBPM engine and Eclipse is included with it). I open it from a command prompt. When I opened the Eclipse I found it is empty as it is installed recently. no projects or tabs or anything.

I reopened the project I am working on and found that the main file that containing the code is empty (it is one line with hidden words). I opened the project from its location on the hard disk and I found the file is also empty but I can see that there is something on it.

I tried to open the project on Netbeans but the problem is still exist. I tried to open the file from the local history but I found nothing in the history. Unfortunately I didn't take a backup from my last work. I don't know what to do right now, if you can help it will be appreciated. I attached here a picture for the eclipse with the empty file:

[image: eclipse error image]

Answer (score 0):

If the project is already deployed in some server then you can decompile them from deployed folder(i.e : webapps folder of Tomcat)